# jquery script interfering with fancyBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I've got a row of buttons, one which toggles a hidden subscription div(#subscribe-pop) and shows another hidden class(.thanks) with a "thank you" message once the submit button is clicked. I'm finding the little script I've got is stopping fancyBox from loading my video for another button. I had the same issue when trying to use the Orbit slider. Could the 'e.stopPropagation' be interfering with them from loading?
Anyone have any idea how I can resolve this?

```
$('html').click(function() {
    $('#subscribe-pop').hide();
    $('.thanks').hide(); 
 })

 $('.innercont').click(function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
 });

$('#link').click(function(e) {
 $('#subscribe-pop').toggle();
 });

$('#mc_embed_signup .button').click(function(e) { 
 $('#subscribe-pop').hide(); 
 $('.thanks').toggle(); 
 });

 $('#mc_embed_signup .cancel').click(function(e) { 
 $('#subscribe-pop').hide(); 
 });

$('.thanks').click(function() { 
 $('.thanks').hide(); 
 });
```

Comment: What error are u getting on the console of the browser?

Comment: TypeError: $(...).fancybox is not a function
$('.fancybox').fancybox();

I took that straight from the demo page source. I'm also getting TypeError: $(...).nivoSlider is not a function
afterLoad: function(){} // Triggers when slider has loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TypeError: $(...).fancybox is not a function $('.fancybox').fancybox();
```

This tells that ,it seems like you are not loading Fancybox js files, try checking if the js and css files for Fancybox plugin are loaded properly ..or check if proper supported version of jQuery library are loaded..

Comment: Or could it be because he has a jQuery conflict of the $

Comment: Aditya, I checked all that; if I leave the code as is and remove the code to show/hide my divs it works fine.

Comment: My apologies, it was nivoslider interfering not the code mentioned earlier. I've stripped it down to 2 pages; one with nivoslider and one without.. http://bit.ly/Mv4lsZ and http://bit.ly/1fnan8W

Comment: @user2315675 : it's not nivoslider, it's because you are loading 3 different versions of jQuery (when you would normally need only one)

Comment: hah yeh I know, I started playing around to see if different versions would maybe stop conflictions. The version of nivoslider I have doesn't work with jquery-1.9.0.min.js or jquery-1.10.1.min.js and I couldn't get fancybox to work on an earlier jquery version

Comment: So did that help? , are you facing any issues?

Comment: Yes! I got a newer nivoslider version so I'm only using jquery-1.9.0.min.js now. Thanks alot of your help guys